# Flutter Navigation shows a black 404 screen when going back from a page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I'm facing this issue with Navigator in Flutter where when I go back from a page I get redirected to a black 404 page.

This is the navigation flow:

- Login screen
- HomePage screen

After being logged in, I am redirected to the Homepage and I shouldn't be able to go back to a previous screen, but if I swipe to the right I'm shown a black page with a 404 label and I can't move from there. Thank you in advance for any help!

Here I provide some code:

```
class SignInPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/signIn';

  const SignInPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                const Positioned(
                  left: -20,
                  top: -20,
                  child: AnimatedCircle(color: AppColors.lightBlue),
                ),
                const Positioned(
                    right: -50, top: 150, child: AnimatedCircle(color: AppColors.lightOrange)),
                const Positioned(
                    bottom: 60, left: -70, child: AnimatedCircle(color: AppColors.lightGreen)),
                const Positioned(
                    right: -50, bottom: -60, child: AnimatedCircle(color: AppColors.lightRed)),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                    Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 8,
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimens.SPACING_XL),
                      child: StyledButton.outlined(
                        title: 'Sign in with Google',
                        leading: Image.asset('assets/images/google.png', scale: 30),
                        onPressed: () async {
                          final res = await Authentication.signInWithGoogle();
                          await Authentication.userSetup(res.user!);
                          Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(HomePage.routeName);
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/homepage';

  static const _padding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 6.0);
  static const _dividerOptions = 30.0;


  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ItemsProvider(),
      child: Consumer<ItemsProvider>(
        builder: (_, provider, __) => Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          appBar: AppBar(
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            actions: [
              IconButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/user'),
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
            ],
          ),
          floatingActionButton: Visibility(
            visible: provider.buttonVisibility,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "btn1",
                backgroundColor: AppColors.red,
                child: const Icon(Icons.add, color: AppColors.splashColor),
                onPressed: () {
                  showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    isScrollControlled: true,
                    builder: (context) => buildModal(context, provider),
                  );
                }),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: _padding,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TopCard(
                    itemCount: provider.itemsCount,
                    onPressed: () {
                      provider.deleteAllItem();
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                  ),
                  const Divider(
                    height: _dividerOptions,
                    thickness: 1.0,
                    indent: _dividerOptions,
                    endIndent: _dividerOptions,
                  ),
                  const Expanded(
                    child: ItemsList(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }

  SingleChildScrollView buildModal(
    BuildContext context,
    ItemsProvider provider,
  ) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
      child: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(),
        child: AddItemScreen(args: AddItemScreenArguments(provider.addItem)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: **Partially solved** 

I replaced `Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(HomePage.routeName);` with  `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(HomePage.routeName);`.
But the problem persists when I build the app with the user is already logged in

Comment: you can try wrapping your HomePage widget with [WillPopScope widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WillPopScope-class.html). It'll prevent action pop from HomePage